# How to create a kelvin cell with cylindrical struts?

Tags: modeling

I have already created a kelvin cell but with square struts as shown in the first picture. How do I turn the square struts into cylindrical like the second picture?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add *Skin* modifier, switch to *Edit* mode and with all vertices selected adjust *Vertices Data* > **Mean Radius X, Y** to something smaller, here 0.02 (*3DView > Sidepanel > Item*) ...

[image]

Add *Subdivision modifier > Catmull-Clark,* *Displace modifier > Strength* 0.05

[image]

Comment: ..and to get your basic shape use the built-in Mesh: Extra Objects addon and Add > Mesh > Math Function > Regular Solid. Then on the bottom-left Operator menu select "Truncated Octahedron" from the bottom Preset popup menu. Now go into Edit mode and use the Mesh > Cleanup > Limited Dissolve menu to get rid of the extra edges.

Comment: .. or an octahedron with all its vertices bevelled by 33.33%

Comment: I was not able to reproduce you settings before you indicated mean radius for skin... but your answer is better! +1

Comment: Or, to add to the comment from @RobinBetts as an alternative, when you have the built-in addon _Add Mesh: Geodesic Domes_ enabled, you can _Add_ > _Mesh_ > _Geodesic Dome_ and choose _Class: Class 1_, _Hedron: Octahedron_ with _Shape: hex_ and you will also get the desired object.

Comment: Hello, vklidu I tried what you have recommended but It didn't work. When you choose the modifiers, did you change the Branch smoothing ? And in the subdivision modifier did you chose Catmull-Clark or Simple?

Comment: @JohnPsihias Since he did not write anything I would expect he used the default settings. Which means _Branch Smoothing_ is 0, and in the _Subdivision Surface_ modifier _Catmull Clark_ (otherwise it will not look so rounded). I did this and it looks exactly like his screenshot (I have set the _Mean Radius X/Y_ for the _Vertices Data_ to 0.01). By the way, more _Mean Radius_ and less _Strength_ for displacement will give you less sharp corners but reduce the risk of overlapping geometry.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann ... 100% correct :) Thank you ... extended.

Comment: @lemon sorry for incomplete description (morning rush) ... when I looked closer OP's reference you matched exactly the same system :)

Comment: @vklidu but the geometry/topology you've generated is very good (better the 'mine')

Answer (score 9):

Using geometry nodes, you can place a sphere at each summit and bevel the edges with a curve circle.

Junctions won't be visible when rendered.

[image]

---

A 3.5 version: should not make a difference except for the shade smooth node.

[image]

Comment: +1  :) Great ... I wanted to try this too, but I was skeptic about junctions ... very nice result.

Comment: When I tried your method I could not get the desired object. Also, when I create the "Set shade smooth" option It doesn't give me the option to choose from edge or geometry.

Comment: What is your Blender version?

Comment: Version: Blender 3.6

Comment: The file I have uploaded is a 3.5 version and it works.